For Prime Monic Polynomial $P$ Over $\mathbb{F}_5$: There's a Solution to $y^2 \equiv x \pmod{P}$ if and only if $P(0)$ Is a Square Modulo 5
I need to show that if $P$ is a prime and monic polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_5$, such that $P(x) \neq x$, then there is a solution to $y^2 \equiv x \pmod{P}$ if and only if $P(0)$ is a square modulo 5. I'm struggling with the first direction ($\Rightarrow$):
I know that if there is a solution to $y^2 \equiv x \pmod{P}$, then the Legendre symbol of $x$ over $P$ with $d = 2$ is equal to 1 — i.e.,
$$
x^{(|P|-1)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod{P}.
$$
Therefore, there exists a polynomial $Q(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$ such that:
$$
Q(x) \cdot P(x) = x^{(|P|-1)/2} - 1.
$$
I would like to show that $P(0)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, and then, by a theorem from Number Theory, I'll get that there exists a solution to $t^2 \equiv P(0) \pmod{5}$, i.e., $P(0)$ is a square modulo 5 — but I can't find a sufficient reason for $P(0)$ to be $1 \pmod{5}$ or $4 \pmod{5}$.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Does $\lvert P\rvert$ mean the size of the splitting field of $P$?
